# How to Migrate and seed before the full test suite in Laravel with in memory database?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm trying to set up the test environment in my Laravel project.
I'm using http://packalyst.com/packages/package/mayconbordin/l5-fixtures with json for the seeding with a sqlite in memory database and calling:

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

in my **setUp** function but this is executed before every single test which it can grow to thousands in this project.

I tried the **setUpBeforeClass** but it didn't work. 
I think there because the **createApplication** method is called in every test and that reset the whole application and also wasn't loading the fixtures from the json probably for the same reason.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how I did it in case someone else is struggling with the same, I created a base `testClase` class that inherits from Laravel's and did this:

```
/**
 * Creates the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */
public function createApplication()
{
    return self::initialize();
}

private static $configurationApp = null;
public static function initialize(){

    if(is_null(self::$configurationApp)){
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        if (config('database.default') == 'sqlite') {
            $db = app()->make('db');
            $db->connection()->getPdo()->exec("pragma foreign_keys=1");
        }

        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('db:seed');

        self::$configurationApp = $app;
        return $app;
    }

    return self::$configurationApp;
}

public function tearDown()
{
    if ($this->app) {
        foreach ($this->beforeApplicationDestroyedCallbacks as $callback) {
            call_user_func($callback);
        }

    }

    $this->setUpHasRun = false;

    if (property_exists($this, 'serverVariables')) {
        $this->serverVariables = [];
    }

    if (class_exists('Mockery')) {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    $this->afterApplicationCreatedCallbacks = [];
    $this->beforeApplicationDestroyedCallbacks = [];
}
```

I overwrote the `createApplication()` and `tearDown()` methods. I changed the first one to use the same `$app` configuration and remove the part of the `teardown()` where it flush `$this->app`.

Every other of my test has to inherit from this TestClass and that's it.

Everything else didn't work. This works even with in memory database, it's 100s times faster.

if you are dealing with user session, once you log the user in you will have to log him out in tear down, otherwise the user will be logged in because the app environment is never reconstructed or you can do something like this to refresh the application every time you want:

```
protected static $applicationRefreshed = false;

/**
 * Refresh the application instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function forceRefreshApplication() {
    if (!is_null($this->app)) {
        $this->app->flush();
    }
    $this->app = null;
    self::$configurationApp = null;
    self::$applicationRefreshed = true;
    parent::refreshApplication();
}
```

And add this to the `tearDown()` before the `$this->setUphasRun = false;`:

```
if (self::$applicationRefreshed) {
        self::$applicationRefreshed = false;
        $this->app->flush();
        $this->app = null;
        self::$configurationApp = null;
}
```

Comment: that is awesome! Thanks for this solution) Only one question: if I want to force refresh application then migrations and seeding will run again?

Comment: Yes melihovv: everything inside  if(is_null(self::$configurationApp)){..... in the initialize() function wil lrun only when forceRefreshing the application, in this case I'm calling migrations and seeds in there.

Comment: I've been searching for this solution for the last 24 hours. I spent at least of 14 hours searching this solution. Thanks a lot. I wish I could treat you a cup of coffee. :)

Comment: I'm very surprised that it isn't easier in Laravel to refresh/seed the database once at the start of test suites. But https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test didn't get me what I hoped for.

Answer (score 6):

create file in your project `testrunner` with this content (also prepare  `.env.testing` file with testing environment variables) :

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --env=testing
php artisan migrate --env=testing --seed
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

And give permission to execute by command `chmod +x testrunner` and execute it by `./testrunner`. Thats all :)

Comment: This won't run the migrate commands with the test environment (different database, sqlite in memory).

Comment: so for tests, may be change your database to MySql?

Comment: the real environment has a mysql database and we want to use in memory for testing, at least for now that's the plan.

Comment: You can add if statement with some DB query  which will detect that command migrate and seed was run or not. If not then you will run `Artisan::call('migrate');...`

Comment: the good place to do it is 'class TestCase` in your tests directory.

Comment: Does'nt work, apparently Laravel destroys the whole environment when tearing down a test. I commented the lines when it sets $this->app to null and flush it and it doesn't work either. I'm guessing  this is going to be a dead end with in memory database at least. I'll try some more stuff and see if it works.

Comment: @FranklinRivero if you come up with anything useful, consider answering your own question for others (me) interested in this.

Comment: I got the migrations running only once already, not the seeding yet, but it seems that i'm getting there.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

How about setting up the database using a migration and seeds and then using database transcations? (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test)

I wanted to be able to set up my test database via artisan like this:

```
$ php artisan migrate --database=mysql_testing
$ php artisan db:seed --database=mysql_testing
```

As you can guess, I'm using mysql, but I don't see why this shouldn't work for sqlite.
This is how I do it.

**config/database.php**

First add the test database info to your config/database.php file, under your current database info.

```
'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
        'mysql_testing' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
    ],
```

If you do it like this, don't forget to add DB_TEST_DATABASE to your  **.env** file:

```
DB_DATABASE=abc
DB_TEST_DATABASE=abc_test
```

**phpunit.xml**

Any values set in the phpunit.xml file, under  overwrite values given in the .env file. So we tell phpunit to use the "mysql_testing" database connection instead of the "mysql" database connection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    ...
    <php>
        ...
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
</php>
```

**Test class**

My test classes look like this:

```
class MyTest extends \TestCase
{
    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testSomething()
    {
```

---

### Option 2

Here the database is reset before every test, which is why I prefer Option 1. But you might be able to get it to work the way you like.

I tried this once before, and it might work for you.

**tests/TestCase.php**
Extend the test case, to load a new .env file, .env.testing

```
<?php

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        /** @var $app \Illuminate\Foundation\Application */
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

**.env.testing**

Create this new .env file and add in the database details

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=xxx

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=abc_testing
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxx
```

In the **test class**:

Use PDO to drop and recreate the database - easier than trying to truncate everything.
Then use artisan to migrate and seed the database.

```
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $config = parse_ini_file(".env.testing");
        $username = $config['DB_USERNAME'];
        $password = $config['DB_PASSWORD'];
        $database = $config['DB_DATABASE'];
        $host = $config['DB_HOST'];

        // Create test database
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$host}", $username, $password);
        $connection->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " . $database);
        $connection->query("CREATE DATABASE " . $database);
    }

    public function testHomePage()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('db:seed');

        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Home')
             ->see('Please sign in')
             ->dontSee('Logout');
    }
```

Comment: That will work with mysql I guess, but I'm using an in memory database o it needs to me migrated/constructed and seeded when the test are running, I just want to do it once for every test. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with a second option. It resets the database after every call, not every class, but it might help you. Good luck :)

Comment: I need Artisan::call('migrate');   Artisan::call('db:seed'); to be executed only once for the whole testSuite, not for every test. Any thoughts?

Comment: This will work. I have tried the second option, but the tests are so slow, too slow: 6 minutes instead of 0.006 seconds

Answer (score 1):

The main approach in the above solutions is to run all migrations for all tests. I prefer an approach to specify which migrations and seeds should run for each test.

It may be more worthwhile on big projects as this can reduce timings for tests by about 70% (using the sqlite in-memory DB as already explained above). For small projects, it's maybe a bit too much faffing about. But anyway...

Use these in TestCase:

```
/**
 * Runs migrations for individual tests
 *
 * @param array $migrations
 * @return void
 */
public function migrate(array $migrations = [])
{
    $path = database_path('migrations');
    $migrator = app()->make('migrator');
    $migrator->getRepository()->createRepository();
    $files = $migrator->getMigrationFiles($path);

    if (!empty($migrations)) {
        $files = collect($files)->filter(
            function ($value, $key) use ($migrations) {
                if (in_array($key, $migrations)) {
                    return [$key => $value];
                }
            }
        )->all();
    }

    $migrator->requireFiles($files);
    $migrator->runPending($files);
}

/**
 * Runs some or all seeds
 *
 * @param string $seed
 * @return void
 */
public function seed(string $seed = '')
{
    $command = "db:seed";

    if (empty($seed)) {
        Artisan::call($command);
    } else {
        Artisan::call($command, ['--class' => $seed]);
    }
}
```

Then call migrate() and seed as required in individual tests, eg:

```
    $this->migrate(
        [
            '2013_10_11_081829_create_users_table',
        ]
    );
    $this->seed(UserTableSeeder::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created `.env.testing` file which was copied from `.env.example` file. Then, I added database information into this file like this.

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=<generate your app key>
...
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=:memory:
```

In the terminal, you can run the migration artisan command with option `--env` like this.

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --env=testing
```